# Is there a way to run Qt(c++) based program without Qt installed?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt project already finished. It runs well and everything.

However, I don't know how to run it on a computer that does not have Qt installed.

Comment: This question has been asked many, many times. Please use the search feature instead of asking a new question.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment.html

Answer (score -2):

You must build your QT libraries statically and thus build your app statically, go [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows) for more information.

Comment: No you don't. You *may* build it statically. You can also deploy the application including the shared libraries required.

Comment: The poster said "I don't know how to run it on a computer that does not have Qt installed."...statically don't need QT pre installed...so I gave an option..please remove -1.